# Error when uploading product content on iTunes connect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am working on project which download content from iTunes connect when user purchase. but I can't upload product content on iTunes with application loader. I am getting following error during upload

**ERROR: ERROR ITMS-4000: "The package can't include two files with the same name 'mzl.kzekbupn.png' but with different size or checksum." at Software/SoftwareMetadata/SoftwareInAppPurchase**

[image]

Comment: So look for two files named `mzl.kzekbupn.png`... they either need to be the same exact file, or renamed differently.

Comment: actually there is no file with name mzl.kzekbupn.png in package. But possibly if error regarding screenshot image for IAP review then both uploaded files are same.

Comment: both uploaded file means uploaded screenshot on itunes store and application loader

Comment: What is the actual filename? It's odd how they would list `mzl.kzekbupn.png` if it doesn't even exist.

Comment: There is only 2 png files in package and those are icon.png and happy.png but no mzl.kzekbupn.png file. I am not sure what is this error about.

Comment: and even not sure what is this path "Software/SoftwareMetadata/SoftwareInAppPurchase"

Comment: Maybe try 'View Log' and see if it shows anything additional beyond what is already shown.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haha!

I got it!

So, I got the exact same message, except mine was complaining about "screenshot.jpg".

I have multiple in-app purchases I have uploaded, and the "screenshot.jpg" is the Screenshot for Review: in the "Info" tab of the In-App Purchases section of the App Loader.  Somewhere it must have gotten corrupted or something.

The App Loader creates an xml file of all the In-App purchases (see below) and if there's a discrepancy in the checksum of a file that's referred to more than once, it creates this error.  And even though I had stopped using "screenshot.jpg" it was still being referred to when creating the xml file.

So, my solution was to post the same screenshot through all the purchases of the app.
[App Loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x76BR.png)

So after going through all my In-App purchases and adding the new screenshot, I was able to push it through.

There might be a more elegant way to access the xml file, but I'm posting what worked for me.

Good luck!

```
            <in_app_purchase>
                <locales>
                    <locale name="en-US">
                        <title>Shakespeare: Antony and Cleopatra</title>
                        <description>A Shakespeare classic.</description>
                    </locale>
                </locales>
                <review_screenshot>
                    <file_name>screenshot.jpg</file_name>
                    <size>74368</size>
                    <checksum type="md5">d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e</checksum>
                </review_screenshot>
                <read_only_info>
                    <read_only_value key="iap-status">Ready to Submit</read_only_value>
                </read_only_info>
                <product_id>scenerunner.scenerunner.antony_and_cleopatra</product_id>
                <reference_name>Shakespeare: Antony and Cleopatra</reference_name>
                <type>non-consumable</type>
                <products>
                    <product>
                        <cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
                        <intervals>
                            <interval>
                                <start_date>2017-06-22</start_date>
                                <wholesale_price_tier>3</wholesale_price_tier>
                            </interval>
                        </intervals>
                    </product>
                </products>
                <has_hosted_content>true</has_hosted_content>
                <software_assets>
                    <asset type="in-app-purchase-content">
                        <data_file>
                            <file_name>Antony_and_Cleopatra.pkg</file_name>
                            <size>78782</size>
                            <checksum type="md5">44c282b4fe09115b7d8ed0f6415a215a</checksum>
                        </data_file>
                    </asset>
                </software_assets>
            </in_app_purchase>
```